# How do I get the values from the inputs that *ngFor generate in my .component.ts file?

Tags: angular, firebase, ngfor

As said in the title, I want to get the values from my generated inputs. How can I do that so I can work on them in my `.ts` file?

Here is the code so far for my `blabla.component.html`:

```
    <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" class="form-horizontal">
    <input name="codeB" ngModel #codeB="ngModel" id="codeB" type="text" class="form-control frm" placeholder="Code Barre" />
    <input name="name" ngModel #name="ngModel" id="name" type="text" class="form-control frm" placeholder="Name Produit" />

    <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr *ngFor="let mag of listMagasins | async">
                <td>
                    <h4>{{mag.name}}</h4>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="prix" ngModel #prix="ngModel" id="prix" type="text" 
                    class="form-control frm" placeholder="Price product" required />
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>

    <!--<input name="nameMag" ngModel #nameMag="ngModel" id="nameMag" type="text"
     class="form-control frm" placeholder="Magasin" />-->

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Ajouter</button>
</form>
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Thanks AL. for the edit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by naming things uniquely instead of naming each input `prix` and, if we want the values in the TS, using `ViewChildren`:

**component.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let mag of listMagasins | async; let i = index;">
            <td>
                <h4>{{mag.name}}</h4>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="prix{{i}}" ngModel #prix="ngModel" id="prix" type="text" 
                class="form-control frm" placeholder="Price product" required />
            </td>
        </tr>
```

**component.ts**

```
import {ViewChildren} from "@angular/core"

export class ComponentClass {
     @ViewChildren('prix') inputs;
<...>
}
```

Which will set our form up to have separately bound controls and give us the inputs in the TS file.

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hxofX9jFKv7gW0QTUF50?p=preview) you can mess with

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!